# How to log in to a SQL Server using pyodbc in a Virtual Machine (VMware)?

Tags: sql-server, virtual-machine, pyodbc

I've always accessed my University's database using pyodbc in my own machine. However, when I try to use the same code (below) in a Virtual Machine (VMware) I receive an error (translated from Portuguese to English):

```
import pyodbc

server = 'beirute-01'

database = 'RAIS'

port= '1433'

username = 'gabrielcp2'

password = '*****'

driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT='+port+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()


    -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------
OperationalError Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\GABRIE~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2064/1387256718.py in <module>
      11 driver= 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
      12
---> 13 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT='+port+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD=' + password)
      14
      15 cursor = cnxn.cursor()

OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Timeout Error [258]. (258) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Logon timed out (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Cannot complete login process due to pre-logon response delay (258)')
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: Can you `ping` the server that is hosting the SQL Server instance from the VMware virtual machine (guest)? Is the guest machine using Bridged networking, NAT, or something else?

Comment: Clearly you can't reach the SQL Server instance using the given details. So what diagnostics have you done so far? Can you use SSMS with the same details? Can you ping it? Have you configured `Remote Connections` and TCP? Have you created a firewall exception for it? Is it a named instance or a default instance? If the former, is it actually on a static port 1433 (unlikely unless you set it), otherwise you need to specify the instance name and start the SQL Browser service on the server.